# In which file is most-positive-fixnum defined in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, gdb, elisp, x86-64

Question is as stated. Where is most-positive-fixnum defined?
lisp.h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `src/data.c`

```
DEFVAR_LISP ("most-positive-fixnum", Vmost_positive_fixnum,
             doc: /* The largest value that is representable in a Lisp integer.  */);
Vmost_positive_fixnum = make_number (MOST_POSITIVE_FIXNUM);
XSYMBOL (intern_c_string ("most-positive-fixnum"))->constant = 1;
```

Comment: For completeness, MOST_POSITIVE_FIXNUM is defined in lisp.h .